How to handle an expired refresh token in ktor?
I use bearer and refresh tokens in ktor as described Here https://ktor.io/docs/client-bearer-auth.html
What ist not mentioned in the docs is how the ktor auth module behaves when a token refresh ist required but the refresh token ist expired as well.
I'd like to send the user to the login page when the refresh token ist expired but I don't know how

Detect Expired Refresh Token:
The refresh token expiry should ideally be checked at the time of attempting to use it for generating a new access token.
This can involve verifying the token's signature and checking its expiration timestamp.
Respond Appropriately:
If the refresh token is invalid or expired, the server should respond with a 401 Unauthorized or a specific error code/message indicating the token issue.
Prompt Re-authentication:
Upon receiving the error response, the client application should prompt the user to log in again.
Invalidate the Refresh Token:
Expired or invalid refresh tokens should be invalidated and removed from the database or token store if you’re using a persistent store.
Setup Dependencies
Ensure you have the necessary dependencies in your build.gradle.kts or pom.xml for authentication.


dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-sessions")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-gson")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty")
}





import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.sessions.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import java.time.Instant

data class RefreshToken(val token: String, val expiresAt: Long)

class TokenService {
    private val validRefreshTokens = mutableMapOf<String, RefreshToken>()

    // Generates a refresh token with expiration
    fun generateRefreshToken(): RefreshToken {
        val token = generateNonce()
        val expiration = Instant.now().plusSeconds(3600).toEpochMilli() // Expires in 1 hour
        val refreshToken = RefreshToken(token, expiration)
        validRefreshTokens[token] = refreshToken
        return refreshToken
    }

    // Validates the refresh token
    fun validateRefreshToken(token: String): Boolean {
        val refreshToken = validRefreshTokens[token] ?: return false
        return Instant.now().toEpochMilli() < refreshToken.expiresAt
    }

    // Invalidate the refresh token
    fun invalidateRefreshToken(token: String) {
        validRefreshTokens.remove(token)
    }
}

fun Application.module() {
    val tokenService = TokenService()

    install(Sessions) {
        cookie<RefreshToken>("SESSION") {
            cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        }
    }

    routing {
        // Endpoint to refresh the token
        post("/refresh") {
            val refreshToken = call.sessions.get<RefreshToken>()
            if (refreshToken == null || !tokenService.validateRefreshToken(refreshToken.token)) {
                call.respond(
                    status = io.ktor.http.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    message = "Invalid or expired refresh token. Please log in again."
                )
                return@post
            }

            // Generate a new access token and return it
            val newAccessToken = generateNonce() // Simulating a new access token
            call.respond(mapOf("accessToken" to newAccessToken))
        }

        // Simulate login to generate refresh token
        post("/login") {
            val refreshToken = tokenService.generateRefreshToken()
            call.sessions.set(refreshToken)
            call.respond(mapOf("refreshToken" to refreshToken.token))
        }

        // Simulate logout
        post("/logout") {
            val refreshToken = call.sessions.get<RefreshToken>()
            if (refreshToken != null) {
                tokenService.invalidateRefreshToken(refreshToken.token)
                call.sessions.clear<RefreshToken>()
            }
            call.respond(mapOf("message" to "Logged out"))
        }
    }
}




Code snippets don't work with Kotlin. Please replace them with a [code block].
